# Adding a new data model to Malhar-Angular-Dashboard

Tags: angularjs

Im' working on the Malhar Angular Dashboard, based on this github project https://github.com/DataTorrent/malhar-angular-dashboard.

As per the documentation in the link post just above, under the 'dataModelType' heading 1/2 way down:

```
`The best way to provide data to a widget is to specify a dataModelType in the Widget Definition Object (above). This function is used as a constructor whenever a new widget is instantiated on the page.`
```

And when setting up the Widget Definition Objects, there are various options to choose from :

`templateUrl -  URL of template to use for widget content`

`template   -   String template (ignored if templateUrl is present)`

`directive  -   HTML-injectable directive name (eg. "ng-show")`

So when I add my own widget definition `column chart`, I attempt to use the 'template' option; however it does NOT inject the {{value}} scope variable I'm setting.

Using the original `datamodel` sample widget def, it works fine using the 'directive' option. If I mimic this method on my `column chart` definition then it works ! But it doesn't work using the template option.

Here's the 'widgetDefinitions' factory code :

```
  (function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('rage')
    .factory('widgetDefinitions', ['RandomDataModel','GadgetDataModel',  widgetDefinitions])

function widgetDefinitions(RandomDataModel, GadgetDataModel) {
    return [          
      {
          name: 'datamodel',
          directive: 'wt-scope-watch',
          dataAttrName: 'value',
          dataModelType: RandomDataModel    // GOTTA FIGURE THIS OUT !! -BM:
      },
      {
          name: 'column chart',
          title: 'Column Chart',
          template: '<div>Chart Gadget Here {{value}}</div>',            
          dataAttrName: 'value',  
          size: {width: '40%',height: '200px'},
          dataModelType: ColumnChartDataModel
      },
    ];
}       
 })();
```

and here are the factories:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('rage')
  .factory('TreeGridDataModel', function (WidgetDataModel, gadgetInitService) {
      function TreeGridDataModel() {
      }

      TreeGridDataModel.prototype = Object.create(WidgetDataModel.prototype);
      TreeGridDataModel.prototype.constructor = WidgetDataModel;

      angular.extend(TreeGridDataModel.prototype, {
          init: function () {
              var dataModelOptions = this.dataModelOptions;
              this.limit = (dataModelOptions && dataModelOptions.limit) ? dataModelOptions.limit : 100;
              this.treeGridActive = true;
              //this.treeGridOptions = {};
              this.updateScope('THIS IS A TreeGridDataModel...');  // see WidgetDataModel factory           
          },

          updateLimit: function (limit) {
              this.dataModelOptions = this.dataModelOptions ? this.dataModelOptions : {};
              this.dataModelOptions.limit = limit;
              this.limit = limit;
          },

          destroy: function () {
              WidgetDataModel.prototype.destroy.call(this);             
          }
      });

      return TreeGridDataModel;
  });

'use strict';

angular.module('rage')
  .factory('ColumnChartDataModel', function (WidgetDataModel) {
      function ColumnChartDataModel() {
      }

      ColumnChartDataModel.prototype = Object.create(WidgetDataModel.prototype);
      ColumnChartDataModel.prototype.constructor = WidgetDataModel;

      angular.extend(ColumnChartDataModel.prototype, {
          init: function () {
              var dataModelOptions = this.dataModelOptions;
              this.limit = (dataModelOptions && dataModelOptions.limit) ? dataModelOptions.limit : 100;
              this.treeGridActive = true;
              var value = 'THIS IS A ColChartDataModel...';
              //$scope.value = value;
              this.updateScope(value);  // see WidgetDataModel factory           
          },

          updateLimit: function (limit) {
              this.dataModelOptions = this.dataModelOptions ? this.dataModelOptions : {};
              this.dataModelOptions.limit = limit;
              this.limit = limit;
          },

          destroy: function () {
              WidgetDataModel.prototype.destroy.call(this);
          }
      });

      return ColumnChartDataModel;
  });
```

and finally the directives:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('rage')
  .directive('wtTime', function ($interval) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: true,
      replace: true,
      template: '<div>Time<div class="alert alert-success">{{time}}</div></div>',
      link: function (scope) {
        function update() {
          scope.time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
        }

        update();

        var promise = $interval(update, 500);

        scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
          $interval.cancel(promise);
        });
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('wtScopeWatch', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      template: '<div>Value<div class="alert alert-info">{{value}}</div></div>',
      scope: {
        value: '=value'
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('wtFluid', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: 'app/views/template2/fluid.html',
      scope: true,
      controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.$on('widgetResized', function (event, size) {
          $scope.width = size.width || $scope.width;
          $scope.height = size.height || $scope.height;
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

I'd like to know why ONLY the directive option will update the wigdet's data and not the template option.

thank you,
Bob

Comment: also posted at https://github.com/DataTorrent/malhar-angular-dashboard/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I see the problem. The `dataAttrName` setting and `updateScope` method are actually doing something other than what you're expecting.

Look at the `makeTemplateString` function [here](https://github.com/DataTorrent/malhar-angular-dashboard/blob/8bc7659a804e6414f2816d48e24ec6b70c04bd4a/src/controllers/dashboardWidgetCtrl.js#L28-L77). This is what ultimately builds your widget's template. You should notice that if you supply a `template`, the `dataAttrName` does not even get used.

Next, take a look at what [`updateScope`](https://github.com/DataTorrent/malhar-angular-dashboard/blob/635d36a4ac50b099e4de5e4e6cdddaab5f5a4a55/src/models/widgetDataModel.js#L31-L33) does, and keep in mind that you can override this function in your own data model to do what you really want, a la:

```
angular.extend(TreeGridDataModel.prototype, {

  init: function() {...},
  destroy: function() {...},
  updateScope: function(data) {
    // I don't see this "main" object defined anywhere, I'm just going 
    // off your treegrid.html template, which has jqx-settings="main.treeGridOptions"
    this.widgetScope.main = { treeGridOptions: data };

     // Doing it without main, you could just do:
     // this.widgetScope.treeGridOptions = data;

     // And then update your treegrid.html file to be:
     // <div id="treeGrid" jqx-tree-grid jqx-settings="treeGridOptions"></div>
  }
});
```